# Does macOS install updates when you reboot if not explicitly allowed to?

Tags: macos, upgrade, software-update, mojave

On Windows, when updates are available, you are not allowed to reboot your computer without installing them which takes quite a long time.

On my Mac, a normal update is available. [image: macOS update dialog]
If I reboot normally with this button will updates automatically be installed?
[image: restart button]

Comment: Windows is stupid and forces you to update shit.  macOS does not. If you have automatic updates on it will install on restart (if its at a specific time) otherwise it wont.

Comment: @JBis: If you have Windows 10 Pro or better, you can turn off automatic updates so the updates are not downloaded and therefore not installed when you reboot. You will still get notifications that updates are available, but the updates will not download until you ask for them. There is also an option to download and not install, but I have never test this option to see if it works.

Answer (score 3):

On Mac OS X High Sierra you have the choice what to do with updates.

From just checking automatically (or not) to full Install for the OS and applications.

[image]

On Mojave the menu looks different but does the same (you choose).

[image]